# Unable to Add System.ServiceModel Nuget Package in Xamarin Form PCL Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget, portable-class-library

I am trying to follow the official xamarin tutorial to make use of WCF Services from a Xamarin Form PCL project (URL /guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/ on Xamarin website)

However, at the time of referencing the System.ServiceModel nuget package, I get the following error and the package does NOT get installed:

> Could not install package 'System.ServiceModel 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I also tried profile 78 without luck (I removed Windows Phone 8.1 as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) since there is no WCF support).

I tried different profiles for the PCL project as explained [here](http://danrigby.com/2014/05/14/supported-pcl-profiles-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2/), but without success.

Also, I tried using the Package Management Console and got similar error:

> ```
>  PM> Install-Package -Verbose
>   cmdlet Install-Package at command pipeline position 1
>   Supply values for the following parameters:
>   Id: System.ServiceModel
>     GET ... OK
>   Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'System.ServiceModel.1.0.0' with respect to project 'Mobile\MobileCashRegister', targeting '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7'
>   Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'System.ServiceModel.1.0.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
>   Resolving actions to install package 'System.ServiceModel.1.0.0'
>   Resolved actions to install package 'System.ServiceModel.1.0.0'
>   Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Package 'System.ServiceModel.1.0.0' does not exist in project 'MobileCashRegister'
>   Package 'System.ServiceModel.1.0.0' does not exist in folder 'C:\dev\DevCuddlUpSolution\packages'
>   Install-Package : Could not install package 'System.ServiceModel 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7', but the package does not contain any assembly 
>   references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package -Verbose
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
> ```

How can I know which profile needs to be selected for the System.ServiceModel nuget package to be installed successfully?

Please note I am using Visual Studio 2015 Professional and the latest available Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

System.ServiceModel 1.0.0 does not contain any assemblies in any lib folders. It just seems to contain NuGet.exe so you will not be able to use it.

It is also not an official Microsoft NuGet package.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for the hint. After cleaning my project and restarting Visual studio, it appears the compiler does not complain anymore about some missing packages. It compiles correctly without the 3 mentioned nuget packages in this page here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/